# How to set default value for property in a Scenario object (constructor not called!)

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Consider the following:

```
@Given("^this stuff:$")
public void this_stuff(List<ScenarioStuff> stuffList) throws Throwable {
    stuffList.get(0).isHappy();
}
```

and the Feature:

```
Given this stuff:
  |Name|
  |Miguel|
```

and finally, the Scenario object:

```
ScenarioStuff{
private String name;
private boolean happy;
(getters and setters for name and happy, inlcuding:)
public boolean isHappy(){
    return happy;
    }
```

Here's what I found:

- stuffList.get(0).isHappy(); is false;
- It remains false even if  `private boolean happy=true;`
- It remains false with a default constructor for `ScenarioStuff(){ happy=true)`
- The code does not break with a breakpoint in that constructor.

**Question:**

How can I default `happy=true` if it is not provided as a parameter in the Feature table?

Comment: isHappy() is a method.  What is the class definition for ScenarioStuff?  Your feature looks like a scenario outline but <name> doesn't appear anywhere.  Did you mean to use a [Doc String](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#doc-strings)? Please clarify the question.

Comment: isHappy is the getter for happy (see updated code). Name appears in the feature table (see "Given the stuff"). I don't think doc strings apply here, since we're passing a table and not a large piece of text.

Comment: You are passing the string 'Miguel' to a List<ScenarioStuff> stuffList receiver.  That is probably not going to work out well.  Why not accept the string as a String and then create ScenarioStuff explicitly in the step body?

Comment: That's a simplification, actual table has more columns. But using scenario objects is actually pretty common, I   believe (they're simpler than DataTables, I believe)

Comment: [Ah](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables) my bad. Let me think about it.

Comment: Since ScenarioStuff has two instance variables shouldn't your feature table have two columns, 'name' and 'happy'?

Comment: That's precisely it, @MikeJRamsey56 - in some scenarios both columns will be used, while in others only one column will be used (motivation for this is that you don't want to fill your feature specification with more information than what is needed to understand that scenario).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cucumber uses [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io) to convert step definition arguments to Java objects, so to answer this we have to dig in [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io)'s methods for doing this.

As mentioned on [this answer to an XStream question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020217/475829), one option is to use the readResolve method (which XStream apparently uses if available, to set up the object.

In my particular case, after changing the happy variable from `boolean` to `Boolean`, I ended up with an implementation like:

```
ScenarioStuff{
private String Name;
private Boolean happy;

private Object readResolve() {
        if(happy == null){
            happy = true;
        }
        return this;
  }
}
```

I also read that one can implement a converter to marshal/unmarshal the object, but I didn't explore this option as 1)it seemed less simple and 2) I didn't immediately see how one would register this new converter within the cucumber setup.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I added booleans and got them to work too.

```
Scenario: An international coffee shop must handle currencies
Given the price list for an international coffee shop
  | product | currency | price | happy |
  | coffee  | EUR      | 1     | true  |
  | donut   | SEK      | 18    | false |
When I buy "1" "coffee" and "1" "donut"
Then I should pay "1" EUR be "happy" and "18" SEK be "unhappy"
```

Step definition file

```
public class datatable_steps {
    private HashMap<String, Price> intPriceList = new HashMap<String, Price>();
    private int sekSum;
    private int euroSum;

@Given("^the price list for an international coffee shop$")
public void the_price_list_for_an_international_coffee_shop(List<Price> prices) {

    int numPrices = prices.size();
    System.out.println("numPrices = " + numPrices);
    for(Price price : prices) {
        String key = price.getProduct();
        intPriceList.put(key,  price);
    }
}

@When("^I buy \"(\\d+)\" \"(.*)\" and \"(\\d+)\" \"(.*)\"$")
public void i_order_coffee_and_donut(int numberOfFirstItems, String firstItem,
                                     int numberOfSecondItems, String secondItem) throws Throwable {
    Price firstPrice = intPriceList.get(firstItem);
    calculate(numberOfFirstItems, firstPrice);
    Price secondPrice = intPriceList.get(secondItem);
    calculate(numberOfSecondItems, secondPrice);
}

private void calculate(int numberOfItems, Price price) {
    if (price.getCurrency().equals("SEK")) {
        sekSum += numberOfItems * price.getPrice();
        return;
    }
    if (price.getCurrency().equals("EUR")) {
        euroSum += numberOfItems * price.getPrice();
        return;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The currency is unknown");
}

@Then("^I should pay \"(\\d+)\" EUR be \"(.*)\" and \"(\\d+)\" SEK be \"(.*)\"$")
public void should_I_pay_EUR_and_SEK(int expectedEuroSum, String eurHappy, int expectedSekSum, String sekHappy) throws Throwable {
    boolean eurHappyBool = false;
    boolean sekHappyBool = false;

    Assert.assertEquals(expectedEuroSum, euroSum);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedSekSum,sekSum);

    if (eurHappy.equalsIgnoreCase("happy")) {
        eurHappyBool = true;
    }

    if (sekHappy.equalsIgnoreCase("happy")) {
        sekHappyBool = true;
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(eurHappyBool, intPriceList.get("coffee").isHappy());
    Assert.assertEquals(sekHappyBool, intPriceList.get("donut").isHappy());
}
```

}

Class Price looks like this:

```
package runsupport;

public class Price {
    private String product;
    private String currency;
    private Integer price;
    private boolean happy;

    public Price(String product, Integer price, String currency){
        this.product = product;
        this.price = price;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public boolean isHappy() {
        return happy;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mmalmeida Notice that I did not update the constructor in class Price for happy. It worked.  No setters, that is interesting.

Comment: That's because XStream is doing the injection (see my answer). To have the same scenario as my original post (1) remove the happy column on the feature and (2) find a way that happy is true within your the_price_list_for_an_international_coffee_shop method.

Comment: @mmalmeida So the real question is, what happens to instance variables in a class specified in the argument list of the receiving step definition that are not given a value in a feature's data table? And how did happy get a value of true?

Comment: Yes, that is the question (the first one)